# G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP map type covers other elements of site

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

My map is in background and is covered by menus and so on. Map works fine till launching google earth plugin. Plugin creates div id="earth0" that covers almost all menus. I tried to solve that problem with z-index but it did not help...
here is url:
http://turystyka.24gis.pl/
to launch 3D map use icon in upper right corner
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to display 'stuff' on top of the Google Earth plugin is to use an 'iframe shim'

The best example page can be seen here
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html